# MYSql config bind-address set to 0.0.0.0 but netstat shows different on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

[Following this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758339/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-111).  I've successfully edited my my.cnf file to comment out the `#bind-address` value and also tried to specify `0.0.0.0` and the specific IP address I want to allow connections.

I do notice that while doing this my.cnf is linked like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Sep  9 06:21 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

and then this my.cnf is also linked:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep  9 06:23 my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
```

So in reality, I'm editing the mysql.cnf file.

I stop/start the MYSQL server.

I then run the `netstat -nat | grep :3306` and it gives me a:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I then go over to the client and get the Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server_name'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is still listening on `127.0.0.1:3306`. You have not effectively modified the correct `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the bind address to `0.0.0.0` is just part of the steps for allowing it to accept remote connections. Those steps include the rem'ing out explicitly with `# skip-networking`

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
# skip-networking
```

And a server restart.

You then need a user,host combo for login and ideally a `GRANT` to a db to use with adequate (not excessive) rights.

You can see your current users with `select user,host from mysql.user`

Please see the MySQL Manual page on [GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

I wrote a little answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400389) about the wildcard `%` host and other minor details.

An illustration for a test is below:

```
create schema testDB007;
use testDB007;

create table t1
(   id int not null
);

CREATE USER 'jeffrey123z'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass123^';
-- note password is mypass123^

GRANT ALL ON testDB007.* TO 'jeffrey123z'@'%';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'jeffrey123z'@'%';
```

[image]

Now, the blue row above (USAGE) means almost nothing other than the user can login and that is it. The 2nd row shows the `PRIVILEGES` for the db from the `GRANT` cmd.

View user in `mysql.user`:

[image]

Concerning the above picture,

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='jeffrey123z';

select user,host,authentication_string from mysql.user where user='jeffrey123z';
```

The first query above is for prior to MySQL 5.7. The second query is for 5.7 and after. The password is hashed. The host is the wildcard `%` meaning login from any host.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue: mysql configured correctly, `sudo systemctl restart mysql` seemed to work fine, but `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 3306` still gave me `TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)` instead of the expected `TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)`, and I noticed from `ps aux | grep mysql` that `/usr/bin/mysqld` hadn't actually been restarted.

A full reboot was necessary for my new settings to take effect.